# Laravel: Visitor tracker

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I want to track the visitors of my webapp, but I think [tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) is a bit overwhelming(and I don't want to kill my database structure). Someone implemented it successfully and/or use a better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest writing simple middleware that increments a counter based on your needs (per visit / unique IP).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)